# Weird Chrome Issue Where Bootstrap Carousel Text is Hidden Until Stylesheet Updated in Console

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, carousel

I'm noticing a strange bug in Chrome where the inner content (text and buttons) of a Bootstrap Carousel slide is hidden until I make *any* live change to the stylesheet in my console.

The first slide shows the inner content correctly, but when you advance a slide, the content isn't visible.

I'm only noticing this bug in Chrome. Currently using up to date Chrome and Bootstrap.js.

**[Here's the page »](http://dentistryforyoungpeople.com)**

Here's a screenshot of Slide 1 (correct) and Slide 2 (hidden content). To see how the error fixes itself, open your console and make a change to any style to any of the page elements, not just the ones pertaining to this carousel (ie. uncheck and then check a style).

Thanks for your help.

[image: Screenshot of Slide 1 and Slide 1]

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-caption {
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  left: inherit;
  right: inherit;
  bottom: inherit;
}
```

Change the above to the below:

```
 .carousel-caption {
          bottom: 30%;
        }
```

Amend to the above; the inherit elements in this class was causing the issues.